# What is the easiest way to check if a character belongs to a particular set of characters?

Tags: elisp

For example suppose that I would like to show the message "yes" if the current character is "a" or "d" or "x", ....
Of course I can write as below. But it is very long.
I am wondering if there is a more simple way to do it.
In this example the variable is `char-after` and the set is `{a,d,x}`. The problem can arise in other situation.

```
  (defun foo () (interactive)
    (if (or (eq (char-after) ?a ) (eq (char-after) ?d ) (eq (char-after) ?x )) 
    (message "yes") (message "no")))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (if (memq (char-after) '(?a ?d ?x))
      (message "yes")
    (message "no")))
```

`memq` is possible because characters are numbers that can be compared with `eq`.
If you want strings or lists, use `member`, which uses `equal` for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

I like `pcase` a lot, though it **may** be slower in some cases.

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (message
   (pcase (char-after)
      ((or ?a ?d ?x) "yes")
      (t "no"))))
```

Comment: You'll get a message when compiling this: ``Pattern t is deprecated.  Use `_' instead``. By the way, it's not slower in this case, it produces the same `memq` as abo-abo's answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of alternatives, first of all, since you are looking to test against a number of different characters, it looks like a regular expression would do the job more succinctly and, perhaps even faster (really depends on how many characters there will be to test from etc.)

---

Another way is to use `char-table` - a built-in Emacs data-structure for working with characters.  Below is an example followed by explanation:

```
(defun char-handler () (message "I am char-handler"))
(defun special-handler () (message "I am special-handler"))

(defvar test-char-table (make-char-table 'testing 'char-handler))

(set-char-table-range test-char-table ?a 'special-handler)
(funcall (char-table-range test-char-table '?a))
"I am special-handler"
(funcall (char-table-range test-char-table '?b))
"I am char-handler"
```

`make-char-table` creates a sparse array-like structure where keys are characters and the values are whatever you want, but usually symbols pointing to some function.  This data-structure is specifically designed to handle text processing so it should be reasonably fast, but, most importantly, it scales better with more handlers.  It's dynamic (which means that adding or removing handlers is possible while without changing the rest of the code which uses relies on the function using it.

When you call `set-char-table-range` you can also provide things other than single character: ranges of characters given by cons cell with `car` being the first character of the range and `cdr` being the last character.  This helps when you have many characters which have to invoke the same handler.  It also accepts `nil` meaning "all characters in the table".

For more info, such as functions which inspect the table and iterate over its contents see: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char_002dTables.html#Char_002dTables