# Check if a character is in a string

Tags: string, characters

It is easy to present list of allowed characters as string, like `" \n\t"`.

`(char-before)` return integer.

How can I check that a character is in a string?

There is [What is the easiest way to check if a character belongs to a particular set of characters?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7879/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-check-if-a-character-belongs-to-a-particular-set-of-c) where `(memq ch (list ?a ?b))` is suggested.

I think that string is constant and don't need to be evaluated in comparison to `(list ?a ?b)`.

I wrote `(seq-some (lambda (el) (eq el 32)) "a b")` but it also is too high level.

It is possible to convert a character to string: `(string-match "[a b]" (char-to-string 32))`.

If string is a sequence there is probably a function that detects element in a sequence... `(member 32 "a b")` doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can test whether a character is in a string. Here are two:

```
(seq-contains "abcd" char)

(memq char (string-to-list "abcd")) ; Which is just (memq char (append "abcd" nil))
```

(`seq-contains` is similar to what you did with `seq-some`.)